# Python IDLE Auto Closed when I create a new file or open existing file

Tags: python

I am using python3.3.3 IDLE for long time.
Yesterday, it was working well.
But today, when I want to create a new file or open any existing *.py file, IDLE automatically shut down. I can see the new file windows for about 0.1 second, and then both IDLE command line and Editor suddenly closed.

I tried to close all the anti-virus.
I tried to uninstall and reinstall a new python3.3.3
And I am 100% sure I did not installed any software between yesterday and today.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: This is very unlikely with Python but rather with your system integrity, and the reason can vary widely. Let you run IDLE under a debugger.

Comment: I cannot even open one, don't mention running one.

Comment: @MacSanhe: The application opens if you say you can see the window. Run it with a debugger and see why it's crashing.

Comment: I mean I can only keep the console open, once I create new file or open file, then everything automatically shutdown.